# Resources for PSTricks examples

Tags: pstricks, big-list

What resources for PSTricks examples do you know? Please feel free to add nice work of your own here as well!

Background: I am constantly looking for PSTricks examples to get ideas how to solve my problems, how to visualize things or what possibilities I have using PSTricks.

Comment: On the basis of comments on the currently only answer, and the fact this seems to call for it, I've made this CW.

Answer (score 4):

One resource I know are the [examples from TUG (Tex User Group)](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples-list).

Some nice examples we can find at our community (please feel free to add any good example you find at Tex Stackexchange):

- [Improved PSTricks figure for everyone interested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121466/improved-pstricks-figure-for-everyone-interested?rq=1)
- [3D-plotting sine integral (PSTRICKS)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12385/3d-plotting-sine-integral-pstricks?rq=1)
- [Drawing cylinder with PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158953/drawing-cylinder-with-pstricks)
- [Draw a prism in TikZ or PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37442/draw-a-prism-in-tikz-or-pstricks)
- [Drawing a complex transformation using PStricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33544/drawing-a-complex-transformation-using-pstricks)
- [Drawing vector field using PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142010/drawing-vector-field-using-pstricks)
- [How to draw this cube with PSTrick or TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159313/how-to-draw-this-cube-with-pstrick-or-tikz)
- [Improvement of PSTricks code for drawing of balls in a triangular box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112906/improvement-of-pstricks-code-for-drawing-of-balls-in-a-triangular-box)
- [Draw 3D lines between points with PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104215/draw-3d-lines-between-points-with-pstricks)
- [Drawing 3D crystal lattice with tikz/pstricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97271/drawing-3d-crystal-lattice-with-tikz-pstricks)
- [Spirograph, Continuous Rotations in TikZ or PSTricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36352/spirograph-continuous-rotations-in-tikz-or-pstricks)

Comment: That would be more appropriate as a comment to your question than as an answer. Even better: edit your question to add that information.

Comment: My idea of that question was to put each ressource/example in 1 answer to allow comments to the specific ressource/example...

Comment: @matheburg: so it should be declared community wiki and eventually as big list.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't know the option to open a community wiki. Can I still redeclare my question?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting examples can be found on this blog (in french) http://pstricks.blogspot.de/ and here http://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/pstricks/ (in french again).