# Drawing vector field using PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

Are there any PSTricks packages for drawing vector fields?

I have had a look at http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples#vector but I don't fully understand the syntax in the example(s). Also I have had a look at page 23 on http://users.math.msu.edu/users/hensh/latex/pstricks/seminarSS08.pdf but here the code is missing. `:(`

Specifically, I would like to draw the vector field

> `{1, x}`

in the range from -5 to 5 on both axes. Here is the vector field drawn using Mathematica:

[image: vectorfield]

**Update**

I have figured out how to do it (more or less):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{
  pst-plot,
  pst-ode
}

\psset{
  unit=5,
  algebraic,
  algebraicOutputFormat
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(-1.1,-1.1)(1.1,1.1)
   \psaxes[
     dx=0.2,
     Dx=1,
     dy=0.2,
     Dy=1
   ]{->}(0,0)(-1.1,-1.1)(1.1,1.1)
    \psVectorfield[
      arrows=->,
      linecolor=black!60
    ](-1,-1)(1,1){x}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{-0.1}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.1}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.3}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_d}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_e}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.7}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_f}{t | x[0]}{-1}{1}{100}{0.9}{t}
   \psset{
     arrows=-,
     linewidth=1.5pt
   }
    \listplot[linecolor=gray  ]{y0_a}
    \listplot[linecolor=red   ]{y0_b}
    \listplot[linecolor=green ]{y0_c}
    \listplot[linecolor=blue  ]{y0_d}
    \listplot[linecolor=purple]{y0_e}
    \listplot[linecolor=yellow]{y0_f}
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{Vektorfeltet~$\mathbf{F}(x,y) = (1,x)$ med nogle str{\o}mningskurver.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

The problem is that the picture is really only drawn from -1 to 1 on both axes (but I have changed the axes labels). This means that the vector arrows and the curves are too 'flat' compared to if they were drawn from -5 to 5 on both axes.

I tried to change the code to

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{
  pst-plot,
  pst-ode
}

\psset{
  unit=1,
  algebraic,
  algebraicOutputFormat
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(-5.7,-5.7)(5.7,5.7)
   \psaxes[
     dx=1,
     Dx=1,
     dy=1,
     Dy=1
   ]{->}(0,0)(-5.5,-5.5)(5.5,5.5)
    \psVectorfield[
      arrows=->,
      linecolor=black!60
    ](-5,-5)(5,5){x}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{-0.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{0.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{1.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_d}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{2.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_e}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{3.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_f}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{4.5}{t}
   \psset{
     arrows=-,
     linewidth=1.5pt
   }
    \listplot[linecolor=gray  ]{y0_a}
    \listplot[linecolor=red   ]{y0_b}
    \listplot[linecolor=green ]{y0_c}
    \listplot[linecolor=blue  ]{y0_d}
    \listplot[linecolor=purple]{y0_e}
    \listplot[linecolor=yellow]{y0_f}
  \end{pspicture}
 \caption{Vektorfeltet~$\mathbf{F}(x,y) = (1,x)$ med nogle str{\o}mningskurver.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

but then I get the error

```
Runaway definition?
->/ArrowA { moveto } def /ArrowB { BeginArrow 1.  1.  scale  false 0.\ETC.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].
\pst@code ....setopacityalpha  Arrow  EndArrow  } 
                                                  def  
l.28     ](-5,-5)(5,5){x}
```

How do I fix this?

**Update 2**

Here is what I ended up with:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-ode}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \psset{
   algebraic,
   algebraicOutputFormat
 }
  \begin{pspicture}(-5.47,-5.47)(5.85,5.9)      
    \psaxes[
      linecolor=lightgray
    ]{->}(0,0)(-5.5,-5.5)(5.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psVectorfield[
      Ox=10,
      Dx=1,
      Dy=1,
      linecolor=blue
    ](-5,-5)(5,5){x}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-2.1}{2.1}{100}{5.205}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-2.533}{2.533}{100}{5.208}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-2.9}{2.9}{100}{5.205}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_d}{t | x[0]}{-3.226}{3.226}{100}{5.2025}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_e}{t | x[0]}{-3.523}{3.523}{100}{5.2055}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_f}{t | x[0]}{-3.797}{3.797}{100}{5.208}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_g}{t | x[0]}{-4.051}{4.051}{100}{5.205}{t}
   \psset{
     linewidth=1.5pt
   }
    \listplot[linecolor=red!20]{y0_a}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!30]{y0_b}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!40]{y0_c}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!50]{y0_d}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!60]{y0_e}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!70]{y0_f}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!80]{y0_g}
%    \listplot[linecolor=purple]{y0_a}
%    \listplot[linecolor=green ]{y0_b}
%    \listplot[linecolor=red   ]{y0_c}
%    \listplot[linecolor=blue  ]{y0_d}
%    \listplot[linecolor=orange]{y0_e}
%    \listplot[linecolor=gray  ]{y0_f}
%    \listplot[linecolor=yellow]{y0_g}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

**Update 3**

When I use the procedure mentioned by AlexG in the comment to the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/142037/15874) by Marienplatz, I still get an error when compiling from `ps` to `pdf`, i.e. when invoking `ps2pdf`, (but the PDF file looks okay):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-ode}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
 \psset{
   algebraic,
   algebraicOutputFormat
 }
  \begin{pspicture}(-5.47,-5.47)(5.85,5.9)      
    \psVectorfield[
      Ox=10,
      Dx=1,
      Dy=1,
      linecolor=blue
    ](-5,-5)(5,5){x}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-2.1}{2.1}{100}{5.205}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-2.533}{2.533}{100}{5.208}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-2.9}{2.9}{100}{5.205}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_d}{t | x[0]}{-3.226}{3.226}{100}{5.2025}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_e}{t | x[0]}{-3.523}{3.523}{100}{5.2055}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_f}{t | x[0]}{-3.797}{3.797}{100}{5.208}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_g}{t | x[0]}{-4.051}{4.051}{100}{5.205}{t}
    \psaxes[
      linecolor=lightgray
    ]{->}(0,0)(-5.5,-5.5)(5.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
   \psset{
     linewidth=1.5pt
   }
    \listplot[linecolor=red!20]{y0_a}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!30]{y0_b}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!40]{y0_c}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!50]{y0_d}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!60]{y0_e}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!70]{y0_f}
    \listplot[linecolor=red!80]{y0_g}
%    \listplot[linecolor=purple]{y0_a}
%    \listplot[linecolor=green ]{y0_b}
%    \listplot[linecolor=red   ]{y0_c}
%    \listplot[linecolor=blue  ]{y0_d}
%    \listplot[linecolor=orange]{y0_e}
%    \listplot[linecolor=gray  ]{y0_f}
%    \listplot[linecolor=yellow]{y0_g}
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The error is as follows:

```
pstODEsolve RKF45 method; '-' failed step, '+' successful step, 'o' output step : 
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
pstODEsolve RKF45 method; '-' failed step, '+' successful step, 'o' output step : 
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
pstODEsolve RKF45 method; '-' failed step, '+' successful step, 'o' output step : 
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
pstODEsolve RKF45 method; '-' failed step, '+' successful step, 'o' output step : 
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
pstODEsolve RKF45 method; '-' failed step, '+' successful step, 'o' output step : 
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
pstODEsolve RKF45 method; '-' failed step, '+' successful step, 'o' output step : 
oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
pstODEsolve RKF45 method; '-' failed step, '+' successful step, 'o' output step : 
ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooError: /invalidrestore in --restore--
Operand stack:
   (1)   1786   1388   5.0   (2)   1786   1152   5.0   (3)   1786   916   5.0   (4)   1786   679   5.0   (5)   1721   2093   5.0   (1)   1721   2329   5.0   (2)   1721   2566   5.0   (3)   1721   2802   5.0   (4)   1721   3038   5.0   (5)   2117   1962   5.0   (5)   1902   1834   5.0   (x)   1902   1834   5.0   (y)   1902   1834   5.0   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1867   1   3   %oparray_pop   1755   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   1807   53   4   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   1791   53   4   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1171/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:8/20(G)--   --dict:117/200(L)--   --dict:187/300(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Numerical result out of range
Current file position is 259609
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: The `pgfplots` package has these plots under the name [quiver](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=quiver+%5Bpgfplots%5D). There are also PSTricks solution in there.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you. Will you make this comment into an answer or should we just close it?

Comment: I have just re-run the code from the 1st and the 3rd code boxes and they compile without error. I tested with TL2021, and even TL2013 works smoothly. (gs-9.53)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{pst-ode}

\psset{algebraic,algebraicOutputFormat}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5.7,-14.7)(5.7,5.7)      
    \psaxes[linecolor=lightgray]{->}(0,0)(-5.5,-14.5)(5.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psVectorfield[Dx=1,Dy=1,Ox=10](-5,-14.5)(5,5){x}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_a}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{-0.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_b}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{0.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_c}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{1.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_d}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{2.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_e}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{3.5}{t}
    \pstODEsolve{y0_f}{t | x[0]}{-5}{5}{100}{4.5}{t}
    \psset{linewidth=1.5pt}
    \listplot[linecolor=gray  ]{y0_a}
    \listplot[linecolor=red   ]{y0_b}
    \listplot[linecolor=green ]{y0_c}
    \listplot[linecolor=blue  ]{y0_d}
    \listplot[linecolor=purple]{y0_e}
    \listplot[linecolor=yellow]{y0_f}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### My compilation steps

```
echo off    
rem %1 TeX input filename without extension

latex "%~1.tex"

dvips -t unknown "%~1.dvi"

rem I invoke ghostscript directly rather than via ps2pdf

gswin64c -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "%~1.pdf" "%~1.ps"
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess you compiled using `xelatex`; I tried `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf` and started to get a bit frustrated. `:)`

Comment: Hmmm! Then I get some wierd output and an compile error; with `xelatex`, it works all fine.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Even with calling `gs` directly the error occurs. Just move the `\psaxes` line behind the `\pstODEsolve` block and `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf` works fine.

Comment: @AlexG Please see update 3 to my question.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: There is some sort of interference between `\psVectorfield` and `\psaxes`. Just swap both and the error disappears. You may want to temporarily comment out the `\pstODEsolve` block to see that it is not related to the `pst-ode` package. I think you should report this to Herbert.

Comment: Hi @Herbert -- It looks like AlexG has found an error (or at least an incompatibility) with `\psVectorfield` and `\psaxes`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I am afraid Herbert will not receive the message as he hasn't participated yet in the discussion.

Comment: @AlexG Thank you for the notice. I will contact him via e-mail.

Comment: @AlexG A mail is now send to Herbert's TUG address.